# Horizontal align of inline-block divs

Tags: html, css

I have a series of divs inline-block displayed (and with left-right margin of 5%), as you know, once the limit of the first row of divs is reached, the rest of the divs automatically go to a second row and so on (you know, instead of overflowing the parent). However this behavior has a small detail, the elements from the second row are not horizontally aligned with the ones from the first row. I know this is caused because of the margins, still i've got no idea on how to make all elements equidistant. The following code represents the architecture of the section.

```css
.parent_div {
  width: 75%;
  float: right;
  /* The "parent of the parent" has its clearfix class*/
}

.child_div {
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  display: inline-block;
}

h4 {
  display: inline-block;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
}


}
```

```html
<div class="parent_div">
  <div class="child_div">
    <h4>Some text: </h4>
    <p>some info.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="child_div">
    <h4>Some text: </h4>
    <p>some info.</p>
  </div>
  
   <div class="child_div">
    <h4>Some text: </h4>
    <p>some info.</p>
  </div>
  
   <div class="child_div">
    <h4>Some text: </h4>
    <p>some info.</p>
  </div>
  
   <div class="child_div">
    <h4>Some text: </h4>
    <p>some info.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

You can see here again the structure of the divs, and also you can observe that the divs from below are not aligned with the ones from above.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9PAB.jpg

Comment: Thanks for providing your CSS, but can you please provide the relevant HTML as well. External sites may be malicious or flagged by filter systems, and may also be removed later (making the question useless). It would help if you could update your question to list **all** relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the **question itself**. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Comment: I've added the CSS code, and the HTML structure was added since the beginning, hope its okay now. As long as i know, that's all the relevant code. If the imgur link shall be removed is okay, the HTML code already describes the structure, the imgur link only provided a visual representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to amend this would be to set a min-width, so that the columns are at least x% wide - in the snippet, the divs show two at a time on rows which are 75% of the total width, and each child is minimum 35% wide. This way the children are correctly aligned and are of same width.

```css
.parent_div {
  width: 75%;
  float:right;
  /* The "parent of the parent" has its clearfix class*/
}

.child_div {
  margin: 0 5%;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width:35%;
}

h4, p {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent_div">
  <div class="child_div">
    <h4>Some text: How on earth? </h4>
    <p>Dunno... seriously</p>
  </div>

  <div class="child_div">
    <h4>Some text: Where?</h4>
    <p>There on the stair</p>
  </div>
  
   <div class="child_div">
    <h4>Some text: my name </h4>
    <p>Rachel.</p>
  </div>
  
   <div class="child_div">
    <h4>Some text:Hi there </h4>
    <p>Nice day</p>
  </div>
  
   <div class="child_div">
    <h4>Some text: hello </h4>
    <p>it's August</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is also because of the margin, but mostly because of the different length of the content in each div. The best way I could think of achieving what you want is by using grid.

```css
.parent_div {
  width: 75%;
  float: right;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 2%;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, max-content));
}
.parent_div .child_div h4 {
  display: inline-block;
}
.parent_div .child_div p {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent_div">
     <div class="child_div">
          <h4>Some text111: </h4> <p>some info 3234r32.</p>
     </div>

     <div class="child_div">
          <h4>Some text22: </h4> <p>some info 34.</p>
     </div>

     <div class="child_div">
          <h4>Some text 232434: </h4> <p>some infods 33.asr23</p>
     </div>
  
  <div class="child_div">
          <h4>Some text 3243: </h4> <p>some infodsf s34.</p>
     </div>
  
  <div class="child_div">
          <h4>Some text33: </h4> <p>some infodfc fdsf342.</p>
     </div>
  <div class="child_div">
          <h4>Some text22: </h4> <p>some info 34.</p>
     </div>
  <div class="child_div">
          <h4>Some text 3243 234234: </h4> <p>some infodsf s34.sd</p>
     </div>
  
  <div class="child_div">
          <h4>Some text33: </h4> <p>some infodfc fdsf342.</p>
     </div>
  <div class="child_div">
          <h4>Some text22: </h4> <p>some info 34.</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i'm a little bit more familiarized with the max-width property, but still your answer is very much appreciated!